# Error al deployar java jersey con Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

Estoy usando como IDE [Myeclipse CI 10](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/), el código funciona perfectamente al publicar y consumir el servicio desde mi IDE, pero cuando deployeo el servicio he intento consumirlo desde mi servidor Tomcat 8.5 me muestra un error.

Codigo Java

```
package logic;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.resource.Singleton;

@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("test")
@Singleton
public class Principal {
 public Principal(){}

 @GET
 @Path("alfa")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public String hello(){
     return "Hello";
 }
}
```

Uso Postman para hacer pruebas desde mi IDE y funciona.
[image: Consumiendo el Servicio]
Exporto el .war y desde el Manager app de tomcat desplego el .war, se desplega de manera correcta pero cuando lo consumo me muestra el siguiente error

[image: errors]

Configuracion de mi web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Simple</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Configuración de mi /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
 <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPre$
</Context>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando java 9?

Comment: En la configuración de mi proyecto y en el servidor uso java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que tu IDE tenga ya añadido en el classpath el paquete necesario, mientras que Tomcat necesite que añadas a tu proyecto (asumo que usas Maven) la siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: no uso maven pero descargo el .jar y hago la prueba, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Funciona amigo me has salvado la vida, muchísimas gracias Pablo

Comment: Te aconsejo que uses alguna herramienta para hacer el build/deploy, ya sea Maven o Gradle. Simplifica mucho la gestión de dependencias una vez aprendes a usarla

Comment: Seguire tu consejo muchas gracias Pablo.